# Handling http status 500

Tags: iis, cgi

We maintain an old cgi app running is IIS, which handles some soap requests. When the app returns soap exception, it uses http status 200. We want to change it to 500 but with the same soap exception body. It works fine in an internal network, but when user connects from the internet, IIS returns some default html page with "Internal server error" message. I cannot find why and how to change this behaviour?

Comment: Http 200 indicates that the request has been successful, there is no exception in request or application. If the app returns exception, how could its status code is 200? You can check [detailed errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FflX.png) in Error Pages module to show exception message.

Comment: There can be many causes, but first you need to review site bindings to make sure those users across the internet land on the right site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about soap request and response, so client knows there is a problem when SoapFault is returned, no matter which http code is returned. I didn't find, what is correct behaviour in this case (200 or 500).
Anyway, the problem I was facing was that IIS threw away my response body and replaced it with its own. I found the solution finally - modyfying web.config this way:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```